# Merging two sorted linked list algorithm not working when using for loop

Tags: c, linked-list, mergesort

So in my following code, I have two lists. Each of them should be sorted in increasing order and then merged together into one list with `SortedMerge()`.
The code works just fine when in the main I insert the numbers separately:

```
int main()
{
    struct Node *final = NULL;
    struct Node *a = NULL;
    struct Node *b = NULL;

    insert(&a, 15);
    insert(&a, 10);
    insert(&a, 5);
 
    insert(&b, 20);
    insert(&b, 3);
    insert(&b, 2);

    final = SortedMerge(a, b);
 
    printList(final);
 
    return 0;
}
```

But in my case I don't want to insert numbers separately but rather have two arrays and insert them to the list using for loop. The code again merges them together, but does not sort them in increasing order:

```
int main()
{
    int list1[] = { 15, 10, 5 };
    int list2[] = { 20, 3, 2 };

    struct Node *final = NULL;
    struct Node *a = NULL;
    struct Node *b = NULL;
    
    int n1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    int n2 = sizeof(list2) / sizeof(list2[0]);

    for (int i = n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) insert(&a, list1[i]);
    for (int i = n2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) insert(&b, list2[i]);

    final = SortedMerge(a, b);
 
    printList(final);
 
    return 0;
}
```

The following code has both insert separately and with `for` loop.
If for clarity anybody will need the overall code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
 
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
 
void MoveNode(struct Node **destRef, struct Node **source);
 
struct Node *SortedMerge(struct Node *a, struct Node *b)
{
    struct Node *result = NULL;
    struct Node **lastPointer = &result;
   
    while (1) {
        if (a == NULL) {
            *lastPointer = b;
            break;
        }
        else if (b == NULL) {
            *lastPointer = a;
            break;
        }
        if (a->data <= b->data)
            MoveNode(lastPointer, &a);
        else
            MoveNode(lastPointer, &b);
    
        lastPointer = &((*lastPointer)->next);
    }
    return (result);
}
 
void MoveNode(struct Node **destRef, struct Node **source)
{
    struct Node *newNode = *source;
    assert(newNode != NULL);
 
    *source = newNode->next;
    newNode->next = *destRef;
    *destRef = newNode; 
}

void insert(struct Node **head, int data)
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (newNode == NULL)
        printf(" Memory can not be allocated.");
    else {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }
}

void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while (node)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    int list1[] = { 15, 10, 5 };
    int list2[] = { 20, 3, 2 };

    struct Node *final = NULL;
    struct Node *a = NULL;
    struct Node *b = NULL;
    
    int n1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    int n2 = sizeof(list2) / sizeof(list2[0]);

    for (int i = n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) insert(&a, list1[i]);
    for (int i = n2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) insert(&b, list2[i]);
    insert(&a, 15);
    insert(&a, 10);
    insert(&a, 5);
 
    insert(&b, 20);
    insert(&b, 3);
    insert(&b, 2);
    final = SortedMerge(a, b);
 
    printList(final);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The *merge* step of merge sort is supposed to merge two sorted lists into a single sorted list, but your code is running the merge step on two *unsorted* lists. (That is for the overall code that inserts some elements in the `for` loop plus some elements not in the `for` loop. List `a` contains 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5 and list `b` contains 2, 3, 30, 30, 3, 2. I.e. they are not sorted.)

Comment: @BGForDevelopers it merges two lists together, but it does not sort it out in increasing order. Did you check with 1st main code and then second main code? cause it does not sort the list in second case

Comment: You are right my mistake. I already deleted the comment.

Comment: The first thing you ought have checked when this first went wrong is: are my inputs the same? Printing out the original lists before trying to merge would clearly show the problem (as would asserting in `SortedMerge` that the preconditions are satisfied)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `SortedMerge` assumes the lists are sorted in ascending order and you break this assumption: you prepend the elements from the last to the first in the arrays (the function is called `insert`, a confusing choice), but the contents of the arrays in already in decreasing order so you effectively get the list sorted in decreasing order.  Then you prepend more elements, so these lists are unsorted.

- change the insertion loop to `for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) insert(&a, list1[i]);` and do not insert more elements or
- change the array contents so the arrays are in increasing order and do not insert more elements or
- change the `insert` function to insert the new node in the proper place.

Here is a modified version using the latter:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
 
void MoveNode(struct Node **destRef, struct Node **source)
{
    struct Node *newNode = *source;
    assert(newNode != NULL);
 
    *source = newNode->next;
    newNode->next = *destRef;
    *destRef = newNode; 
}

struct Node *SortedMerge(struct Node *a, struct Node *b)
{
    struct Node *result = NULL;
    struct Node **lastPointer = &result;
   
    for (;;) {
        if (a == NULL) {
            *lastPointer = b;
            break;
        }
        if (b == NULL) {
            *lastPointer = a;
            break;
        }
        if (a->data <= b->data)
            MoveNode(lastPointer, &a);
        else
            MoveNode(lastPointer, &b);
    
        lastPointer = &(*lastPointer)->next;
    }
    return result;
}
 
void insert(struct Node **head, int data)
{
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory cannot be allocated.\n");
        return;
    }
    while (*head != NULL && (*head)->data < data) {
        head = &(*head)->next;
    }
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}

void printList(const struct Node *node)
{
    while (node) {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
 
int main()
{
    int list1[] = { 5, 10, 15 };
    int list2[] = { 2, 3, 20 };

    struct Node *a = NULL;
    struct Node *b = NULL;
    
    int n1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    int n2 = sizeof(list2) / sizeof(list2[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        insert(&a, list1[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        insert(&b, list2[i]);

    insert(&a, 15);
    insert(&a, 10);
    insert(&a, 5);
 
    insert(&b, 20);
    insert(&b, 3);
    insert(&b, 2);
    struct Node *final = SortedMerge(a, b);
 
    printList(final);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SortedMerge` function expects two lists sorted in ascending order and merges them into a single list in ascending order.

---

For the first example:

```
    insert(&a, 15);
    insert(&a, 10);
    insert(&a, 5);
 
    insert(&b, 20);
    insert(&b, 3);
    insert(&b, 2);
```

(Note: `insert` inserts at the front of the list.)

- List `a`: 5, 10, 15.
- List `b`: 2, 3, 20

Lists `a` and `b` are in ascending order so are valid for `SortedMerge`.

---

For the second example:

```
    int list1[] = { 15, 10, 5 };
    int list2[] = { 20, 3, 2 };
```

```
    int n1 = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);
    int n2 = sizeof(list2) / sizeof(list2[0]);

    for (int i = n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) insert(&a, list1[i]);
    for (int i = n2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) insert(&b, list2[i]);
```

(Note: `insert` inserts at the front of the list.)

- List `a`: 15, 10, 5
- List `b`: 20, 3, 2

Lists `a` and `b` are in descending order so are not valid for `SortedMerge`.

---

For the third (combined example):

- List `a`: 5, 10, 15, 15, 10, 5
- List `b`: 2, 3, 20, 20, 3, 2

Lists `a` and `b` are not sorted so are not valid for `SortedMerge`.